# Where to get the latest jrockit version

Tags: jrockit

TLS 1.1 support was added in 28.3.9 (which is what I urgently need) - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15289_01/doc.40/e15066/toc.htm

Official page servers 28.2.7 - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/jrockit/overview/index.html

As far as I know, 28.3.11 is the latest and the last version. I am looking for Windows x86-64 version, but unable to find it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Doc ID 1948210.1 (Where To Download the Latest jRockit?) on http://support.oracle.com has all the details.

It says:

The current version on OTN will remain as R28.2.7 and can be downloaded from the following URL:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-jrockit-2192437.html

Customer needs extended support or FMW Support to get to newer jRockit versions (beyond R28.2.7) and can be downloaded from My Oracle Support.

To download the latest JRockit patch set:

- Log into My Oracle Support
- Click on "Patches & Updates" tab
- Click on Product of Family (Advanced Search)
- For the "Product is" choose Oracle JRockit
- For the "Release is" choose your JRockit patch set release
- Choose the Platform
- Hit Search

[JRockit download from Oracle Support](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-jrockit-2192437.html)